# How to handle redirect url for mobile application - OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, okta, okta-api

we are trying to build an android mobile application that would use OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow with PKCE.
while reading more about this, I found we have to pass redirect URL where it would return a `code`.
for web applications, it would make sense to have redirect URL, but how we could have it for mobile application. 
some of the colleagues suggested using an in-app browser that would do this job.
but I don't want to use a browser in my application at all.

can someone please suggest the best way to implement this.

Answer (score 6):

In the past, developers used a custom scheme (e.g. `myapp://`) to catch the redirection response (i.e. `302 Found`) on the client side.

However, malicious developers found a way to steal an authorization code from the custom-scheme invocation process. It is called "authorization code interception attack". [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636), aka PKCE, has been developed as a countermeasure for the attack. See [this article](https://www.authlete.com/developers/pkce/) for technical explanation.

A new way recommended in [BCP 212](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp212) is **Claimed https Scheme URI Redirection**. See [Section 7.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp212#section-7.2) for details.

Vendor-free solutions are AppAuth-* (such as [AppAuth-iOS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) and [AppAuth-Android](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android)) which are available at https://github.com/openid/ .

Finally, note that in-app browsers won't work for OAuth any longer. See [this article](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) for the background of prohibition of in-app browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Okta Android SDK to create your own UI for login. https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-android#Sign-in-with-your-own-UI